# Neo4j Browser blank screen with error when loading json using apoc.load.json

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using neo4j to load a json file which is 103 MB worth.  It has only 6500 records though.

I created a apoc.config in the right Configuration location and added the property:

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

I placed the file in dbmss/<dbms_id>/import/<client_name>/data_dump/<file_name.json>.  I am able to apoc procedure using:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///<client_name>/data_dump/<file_name.json>")
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

However, after ~1 mins 50 seconds, the process stops with a blank browser page.

[image: Neo4j Browser error]

The following error is shown in the console.

```
[14:07:54.869] [info]  Neo4j @ 7687 is up and running!
[14:07:54.885] [info]  Neo4j @ 7474 is up and running!






Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
    at n.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:417)
    at b.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:161:2494)
    at send (/tmp/.mount_neo4j-WfMZ7l/resources/app.asar/dist/main.prod.js:6062:13)
    at /tmp/.mount_neo4j-WfMZ7l/resources/app.asar/dist/main.prod.js:6066:63
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at broadcast (/tmp/.mount_neo4j-WfMZ7l/resources/app.asar/dist/main.prod.js:6066:48)
    at Timeout.onlineCheck [as _onTimeout] (/tmp/.mount_neo4j-WfMZ7l/resources/app.asar/dist/main.prod.js:13066:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I googled somewhere and added:

```
apoc.http.timeout.connect=600000
apoc.http.timeout.read=600000
```

No change.  Still errors out around 1 min 50 seconds.  Not sure what this config is.  It is consistently reproducable.

This happens on all of Ubuntu VM, Ubuntu standalone system and Windows.  Doesn't look like a display issue.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

You are asking the Browser to **display** 103 MB of data, which may be overtaxing it. The Browser is not really designed to display that much data all at once.

TO BE CLEAR: the issue is not that the neo4j server cannot handle huge amounts of inout data (it certainly can), but with asking the Browser to display huge amounts of data.

##### If JSON file contains an array of objects

In this case, the `apoc.load.json` procedure returns each object in a separate row. Try showing just a portion of the array (say, the first 50 items, which will still take up about 800 KB):

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///<client_name>/data_dump/<file_name.json>") YIELD value
RETURN value
LIMIT 50
```

##### If JSON file contains an object that contains an array of sub-objects

In this case, the `apoc.load.json` procedure will return the outer object (with all 103 MB of data) in a single row. If   "items" is the key of the array in the outer object, you can show just a portion of the array (say, the first 50 items) this way:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///<client_name>/data_dump/<file_name.json>") YIELD value
UNWIND value.items AS item
RETURN item
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam.  I will try this.  But still need to load the entire json as I am not allowed to massage or restrict the data which has to be consumed in its entirety, even if we fetch multiple times.  How can I keep changing the limits and iterate/automate the process so as to load everything by and large.

Comment: Actually same results (crashing) even with LIMIT 1.  Not sure what is wrong.  Will the data wrong in some way?  I just can't post the data here.  Please @cybersam, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON file? Is it an array of 6500 objects, or is it an object that contains an array of 6500 sub-objects? If it is the latter, than that explains why `LIMIT 1` also has same problem (since all 103 MB would be in a single `value` row).

Comment: yes you are bang on the target, so to speak @cybersam.  It is an object that contains an array of 6500 sub-objects.  Hence the LIMIT 1 problem.  I am running out of ideas, one of them is to actually try to load a single JSON sub-object, iron out the model as it loads into, and then figure out how many to split them to lead each iteratively.  I really don't see a way to iteratively load, let's say a single JSON sub object, assuming I split it programmatically using Python/Java.  My  main task is to convert this to CSV using jq and then load.  That is affected mainly because of this limitation.

Comment: we are seriously considering neo4j and the customer, who is a major telecomm. gaint in the US is fascinated by that.  I have bits and pieces of stuff to give them, nothing more, that hurts the most.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to avoid displaying too much data in your case. But you should note that your issue has to do with trying to **display** 103 MB of data in the Browser. If you instead just want use `apoc.load.json` to load data into the DB (without displaying all of it) then there is no such problem (but you should still take care to avoid memory issues, and should look into using [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/) to break up the loading task into smaller batches).